# Having an ItemCollection within a ListBox?

Tags: wpf, xaml, listbox

I want know why the following xaml code does not work.

```
<ListBox>
<ListBox.Items>
<ItemCollection>
<ListBoxItem><TextBlock>A</TextBlock></ListBoxItem>
<ListBoxItem><TextBlock>B</TextBlock></ListBoxItem>
<ListBoxItem><TextBlock>C</TextBlock></ListBoxItem>
</ItemCollection>
</ListBox.Items>
</ListBox>
```

It says ***The type "ItemCollection" does not include any accessible constructor***
What does that message means and any idea how to solve it?

Comment: Just write it without `<ItemCollection>` and `</ItemCollection>`. Besides that the Items property is read-only, the error message is pretty clear, ItemsCollection does not have a public parameterless constructor. You can't create an instance of it in XAML.

Comment: For that matter, you can leave off the `<TextBlock>` tags too.  `ListBoxItem` inherits from `ContentControl`, so direct content will automatically get assigned to the `Content` property and presented as text, e.g., `<ListBoxItem>A</ListBoxItem>`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ListBox>
<ListBoxItem><TextBlock>A</TextBlock></ListBoxItem>
<ListBoxItem><TextBlock>B</TextBlock></ListBoxItem>
<ListBoxItem><TextBlock>C</TextBlock></ListBoxItem>
</ListBox>
```

You don't have to put the ItemCollection and Items tags as WPF will do it internally.